# Bootstrap 5 : show modal with javascript

Tags: javascript, function, bootstrap-modal, show, bootstrap-5

I'm making a neat gallery with **bootstrap 5**, and I wondered how I could **trigger a bootstrap modal without using "data-bs-..." in my HTML** (to avoid duplicating those data- attributes 50 times).

I managed to get a full functionning javascript for the  sources, but the .modal() functions and .show() functions don't seem to work. Here's the thing :

```
function gallery(_src) {
var fullPath = _src;
var fileName = fullPath.replace(/^.*[\\\/]/, '');
var newSrc = "./assets/img/" + fileName;
document.querySelector("div#galleryModal img").src = "./assets/img/" + fileName;

document.getElementById("galleryModal").show(); }
```

I'm blocked on this last javascript line. The objective : trigger #galleryModal.

Thanks for reading, thanks for helping !

Answer (score 15, accepted):

We need to `Create a modal instance` if we want to operate with javascript
check the below code and you find more info https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/components/modal/#via-javascript

```
var galleryModal = new bootstrap.Modal(document.getElementById('galleryModal'), {
  keyboard: false
});


galleryModal.show();
```

Comment: Simple. Effective. Thank you kindly ! :)

Comment: import { bootstrap } from "bootstrap" was throwing errors for me because a bootstrap type was not being exported from "bootstrap". import { Modal } from "bootstrap" instead.